# In Python; How do you skip an invalid value in a 'for loop'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I've got a `for` loop set up to read in an X and Y values from a .csv, so far so good.

However, the .csv is 65,000 rows long! and about 2000 of these are just blank rows.

How do I tell the for loop to ignore / skip blank rows and just get the next set of values?

I've been try to use 'continue' like this...

```
for line in lines:
    #split the content of each line to an array delimited by a comma ,
    pos = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
    if pos == "":
        continue
    else:            
        #set up variables
        x = float(pos[0])*10000
        y = float(pos[1])*10000
        z = 0.0
```

But it doesn't work, whenever it gets to the first blank row it just adds zeros for the rest and I get this error message...

```
ValueError: empty string for float()
```

I did try removing the blank rows in Apple Numbers before Python imports them, but apparently something as simple as removing blank rows is a total ball-ache in Numbers.

I also tried to strip out all the blank variables before the For Loop, but couldn't get that to work either.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, but please keep it simple! (I'm new to this stuff and the more esoteric code goes right over my head).

Comment: So `pos != ""` but `pos[0]` or `pos[1]` is the empty string. Why don't you try checking for `if not pos.strip():` instead of `if pos == "":`?

Comment: "if not pos" is your answer

Comment: three things I would do:  First, check if line is empty, because that is what you are really wanting to know up front.  Second, as @Two-Bit Alchemist mentioned, you want to check the array values, not the array address.  Thirdly, I can see a condition where there is only one value, and pos[0] gets populated, but pos[1] doesn't exist, so that can still bomb out, namely if you have a string like "123123.412" and no commas in it

Answer (score 3):

In the equality check `pos` is no longer a string it is a list.
So you can check if the line itself is empty:

```
for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue
    #split the content of each line to an array delimited by a comma ,
    pos = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',') if x.strip()]
    # make sure you have x and y
    if len(pos) < 2:
        continue
    #set up variables
    x = float(pos[0])*10000
    y = float(pos[1])*10000
    z = 0.0
```

By adding the if condition while defining `pos`, we now discard empty elements.

Comment: it won't fix `ValueError: empty string for float()` error. (blank line in the input leads to `IndexError` not `ValueError`). [EAFP could be used instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23203784/4279)

Comment: e.g., try it with `line = '1,'` (empty 2nd field). If you skip some empty fields then you may get wrong values e.g., `line = ',,3,4'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I added a simple check to prevent that case. Now it should work fine.

Comment: This gets to the end of the file, but when it gets to a blank row it enters 0, 0 rather than skip and go to the next row. I'm using the values to create a spline, so by going back to 0,0 it breaks up the line. - How can I get it to just ignore the blank rows?

Comment: @zedzero, I don't understand how it can enter `0, 0` for a blank line. The first line after the `for` makes it skip blank lines. Also the check after the `if` statement makes it skip empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie for python , but I think you could try the code below. 
My thought is If there is a empty line, the length of line should be 0. Thank you

```
 if not line:
       continue
```

Comment: The Pythonic way of spelling that is simply `if not line:`

Comment: @thebjorn thank you. that is much clean than before.

Comment: even empty line might contain a newline i.e., `if not '\n'` is never `True`. Check for [blank lines (`if not line.strip():`) also is not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203074/in-python-how-do-you-skip-an-invalid-value-in-a-for-loop/23203784#comment35493326_23203269)

Answer (score 0):

From the exception: *ValueError: empty string for float()* I infer that "blank rows" mean something like '1, ,'  in your case i.e., you get an error if *any* of the (first two) fields in a row is blank (contain only whitespace):

```
for line in lines:
    try:
        x, y = map(float, line.split(',')[:2])
    except ValueError:
        continue # skip invalid (for whatever reason) lines
    else:
        # use x, y here
        x *= 10000
        y *= 10000
        z = 0.0
        print(x, y, z)
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/KdmP1B)

```
1,2
# the next line is blank AND IT IS SUCCESSFULLY SKIPPED NO 0,0

# missing second field
70,
# both empty
,
# first empty
,0
# 
,,80,90
3,4
```

#### Output

```
(10000.0, 20000.0, 0.0)
(30000.0, 40000.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: This gets to the end of the file, but when it gets to a blank row it enters 0, 0 rather than skip and go to the next row. I'm using the values to create a spline, so by going back to 0,0 it breaks up the line. - How can I get it to just ignore the blank rows?

Comment: @zedzero: [It does skip blank rows](http://ideone.com/KdmP1B). Provide a minimal input (`len(lines)` ~ 2) that shows the issue if you think otherwise.